# Controller action does not execute when called via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two HttpPost controller actions called Contact and About. And I have a JavaScript function that will transform the related form properties (its action, method, etc.) into an AJAX request and then do something with the return value  / response.

However, when I call the JavaScript function, only the JavaScript portion runs and MVC server side code is not being called.

Can anyone help?

Contact

```
[HttpPost]         
public string Contact(string id)
{
    return "OK";
}
```

About

```
[HttpPost]
public string About(string id)
{
    return "OK2";
}
```

script

```
 $('form').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $('#myForm').html('');
                $('#result').html(result);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: `return false;` cancels the default submit action. You need to submit the form view ajax and handle the return value its success callback. Is an 'About' page really a POST?

Comment: Can you give a link or write a javascript function about this?

Comment: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I wrote  javacript function but don't run. $(function () {
                $('form').submit(function () {
                    
                        $.ajax({
                            url: this.action,
                            type: this.method,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function (result) {
                                $('#result').html(result);
                            }
                        });
                   
                });
            });

Comment: Edit your question with the new code you have tried - too hard to read in comments

Comment: I editted. When I run my project,  Javascript function data is not defined @StephenMuecke

Comment: Change `$(this).serialize(),` to `$('form').serialize(),` (or better, declare the form as the first line - `var form = $(this);` and then `data: form.serialize(),`)

Comment: My contact action method return value is OK. This was not sent to ajax method's result.

Comment: You said the `data` property was not defined - did you mean the `result` (in the success callback)

Comment: Yes,I did. But result and data are null. What is this project's problem?

Comment: You haven't shown the view (does it contain an input named `id`?).

Comment: I know. Id is not important for now. Only, I want to send "OK" value to result when ajax is success. When I run my project, ı want to see result=OK

Comment: finally, it run correctly. Thank you @StephenMuecke

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following since the question didn't mention the specifics...

I'd imagine your page is sort of structured like so:

```
<body>
   <form action="/Home/About" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
     <button type="submit">About</button>
   </form> | 
   <form action="/Home/Contact" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
     <button type="submit">Contact</button>
   </form>
   <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
   <form action="/Home/About/?id=1" method="POST">
     <button type="submit">About</button>
   </form> | 
   <form action="/Home/Contact/?id=2" method="POST">
     <button type="submit">Contact</button>
   </form>
   <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

If so, it should work.

Note that each form contains an input element called id or the id is attached as querystring in the form action attribute.  This is **IMPORTANT** since MVC routing and model binding depends on this since your controller action is requiring an id parameter. i.e. `public string Contact(string id)`.

Also ensure that your action is correctly form i.e. if you are using default action, make sure the controller name is part of the route (i.e. if your controller is called **HomeController** and your action is **Contact**, MVC will expect this particular route (if the catch all route is used: **/Home/Contact**).  If you are using custom routing entry, then ignore this.

Another reason for why the server side action might not be hit is due to your form method.  Your example is expecting as **POST**, but if your form method is **PUT** or **GET** or something else, it will not hit it either.

If you adhere to these 3 things, you will probably will not have the problem.